# Wait for user to accept or decline download before redirect in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, redirect, pdfmake

I have created a script which generates a PDF using PDFMake based on user input and attempts to download that PDF before redirecting the user to a new page. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox, which have separate popups that allow the user to accept the download. However, in IE 11, the popup disappears as soon as the page redirects so the user cannot click 'Save' or 'Open' or whatever they want. Is there a way I can wait for this event to stall the redirect?

I am downloading the PDF instead of opening it as IE cannot open Blob URLs.
This is the JavaScript I have

```
let theForm = document.getElementById('pdf-form');
let documentDefinition = {
  content: [
    { text: 'Text and contents of PDF here' }
  ]
};
pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition).download();
theForm.submit();
```

Basically, I take the form data and generate a PDF with the data, then I want to actually submit the form to add to the database. The PDF is just for the user to have a record.

Comment: So what is your code?

Comment: @epascarello I have added my relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I added `target="_blank"` to the form so that it submits it in a new page, thus I don't have to wait for the user to make a decision.